# What does `() => Unit` mean?

Tags: scala, types, syntax

Like the question says.

This was found in `List[() => Unit]` which was used to store callback functions.

I understand `List[type]` and that `Unit` is a return type of a function that doesnt return anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(T1,...,Tn) => T` is the type of functions that take parameters of types `T1` through `Tn` and return type `T`. So `() => Unit` is the type of functions that take no parameters and have return type Unit. Consequently `List[() => Unit]` is the type of lists containing such functions.

Comment: "parameters of types T1 through Tn", so functions like `f(T1):Unit`, `f(T2):Unit` will be valid type for that list? What about something like `f(T1,T2)`?

Comment: @aitchnyu No. If you have a list of type `List[(T1, T2) => Unit]` then that list stores functions that take two parameters (the first one having type T1 and the second T2) and return type Unit. So you could store a function defined as `f(x:T1, y:T2):Unit` in it, but not one defined as `f(x:T1)` or `f(y:T2)`. Likewise a list of type `List[() => Unit]` only stores functions that take exactly no parameters.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you have a list of functions.  Each function takes no parameters (this is what the open-close parentheses `()` mean) and returns `Unit`, which is a value for no result, similar to void.

In a pure functional world, a function of type `()=>Unit` is useless because it takes nothing and returns nothing.  However, Scala is not a purely functional language; it has side effects.  To be useful, the functions in the list will surely have side-effects.  Since they are callback functions, they also have an idea about when they fire.